# How to allow port 8443 in iptables?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, firewall, iptables

In order to allow input from port 8443, I have inputed the iptables rule:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
```

However, when I type:

```
$ netstat -a
```

There is no reference to https or 8443. The result is:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:6311                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 gauss:ssh               ommited                 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 gauss:ssh               omitted                 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:6311          localhost:48872         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 localhost:8005          [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8009               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:www                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 localhost:48872         localhost:6311          ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:52703                 *:*                                
udp6       0      0 [::]:42168              [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*
```

How can I successfully open port 8443?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that you *didn't* open port 8443? `netstat -a` lists the ports on which something is listening, not the ports that are open w.r.t. the firewall.

Comment: Ah, so if 8443 isn't appearing on `netstat -a` it means that Tomcat is not working with it?

I mean, can I conclude that the problem is with Tomcat and not with firewall?

Comment: That is the conclusion that I would draw.

Comment: I have changed some Tomcat configurations and now it appears on `netstat -a`. However I still can't ping or access 443. What else could be blocking it?

Comment: `ping` is not the right tool for testing a TCP port, because ping uses ICMP.

Answer (score 1):

iptables will only allow the port to get in, it will not "open" the port!

If you want to check what ports are allowed by iptables, you should you `iptables -L -nv`

Comment: Also, since the rule is appended above, you will want to make sure that there isn't a rule with higher precedence to reject or drop it before the rule to accept is processed.

Comment: There was a "drop all" rule before it. However, even if I change the order and let the DROP rule as the last, I can't access or ping localhost 443.